# How can I use actions of ToolbarAndroid component to render different scene of the Navigator?

Tags: react-native

I have got a 'Login' scene (= initial Route) and another scene (different Screen) called 'Test'.

```
var Login = require('./Components/Login');
var Test = require('./Components/Test');
```

I have defined to ToolbarAndroid with a Logo and an action on the right side which when clicked should render the scene 'Test'. Currently I receive the error message "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator.push')"

I have tried different ways to navigate to the 'Test' scene but have not been successful.

```
var ToolbarAndroid = require('ToolbarAndroid');
var QPointsAndroid = React.createClass({

  _onActionSelected: function(){
    this.props.navigator.push({id: 'Test'})
  },
  renderScene: function(route, navigator){
    if ('Login' === route.id) {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <ToolbarAndroid
            title=''
            actions={toolbarActions}
            logo={require('image!logo')}
            style={styles.toolbar}
            onActionSelected={this._onActionSelected()} />
        <Login
            name={route.name}
            navigator={navigator} />
      </View>
      );
    } else if ('Test' === route.id) {
      return (
        <Test
            navigator={navigator} />
      );}},
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        style={styles.container}  
        initialRoute={{
          id: 'Login',
          index: 0,
        }}
        renderScene ={this.renderScene} />
    );}});  
var toolbarActions = [
  {title: 'Profile', icon: require('image!profile'), show: 'always'},
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an error in the line onActionSelected. It should have looked like this

```
onActionSelected={() => {this._onActionSelected(navigator)}}
```

and than I have to pass the navigator to the function:

```
_onActionSelected: function(navigator){
    console.log('check the navigator');
    navigator.push({id: 'Test'});
  },
```